# How to rename folders containing files in node.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fs

The following method works fine when renaming a single folder that contains no files. It does not work when renaming a folder that contains one or more files.

```js
const handleRenameFile = () => {
    const oldPath = `./${directory}/${fileName}`;
    const newPath = `./${directory}/${name}`;
      fs.renameSync(oldPath, newPath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
      });
  };
```

EPERM: operation not permitted, rename './oldPath' -> './newPath'

As such, I'm open to any alternative solution that can accomplish the objective.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_renamesync_oldpath_newpath

> See the POSIX rename(2) documentation for more details.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html

> oldpath can specify a directory. **In this case, newpath must either not exist, or it must specify an empty directory.**